# Database Links - Oracle 10g and Ms Access 2007

Tags: database, oracle, ms-access, database-link

I'm trying to create a link between oracle 10g and ms access 2007 but I don't know how to set parameters in my tnsnames.ora file to access my MS Access db.
I've created new Data Source in ODBC Data Source Administrator with Microsoft Access Driver and selected my access db (.mdb).

In the MS Access I can link between tables and I see data from my Oracle db, but I need to create a database link from Toad or SqlDeveloper so I can change data in MS Access db with some trigger in my Oracle db. When I try to test my db link I get the following error :
Error : ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified, because I don't know what parameters I need to write into my tnsnames.ora file. MS Access db is located on my hard drive. Here is how my tnsnames.ora looks like :

```
accdb =
  (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost) (PORT = 3306)
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = hsodbc)
  (HS=OK)
 )
```

but I'm not sure for PORT and SID.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This article shows how Oracle's Heterogeneous Services can be configured to allow a database to connect to a Microsoft Access database using standard databases links:

http://www.orafaq.com/node/60

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a starting point

http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B10544_01/ch2.htm#1005725